How to match optional group in regular expression
I want a regular expression for using in fluentd for parsing nginx error logs.
The sample row is:
2024/04/15 09:06:29 [error] 3443790#3443790: *176070165 limiting requests, excess: 2.957 by zone "RequestLimitForCommonApi", client: 77.81.151.129, server: test.com, request: "POST /capi/session/forgot HTTP/1.1", host: "test.com", referrer: "https://test.com/"

I'm using the following format for matching log parameters:
format1 /^(?<time>\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[(?<log_level>\w+)\] (?<pid>\d+).(?<tid>\d+): (?<error>.*), (?<client>.*), (?<server>.*), (?<request>.*), (?<host>.*), (?<referrer>.*)/

But some log rows have 'uptime' parameter and some of them don't have.
Now what regular expression should I use to also match the 'uptime' parameter value if exists?
Sample log row with uptime:
2024/04/15 02:01:32 [error] 3443790#3443790: *172976982 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.55.16.251, server: test.com, request: "POST /api/test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:30110/api/test", host: "test.com", referrer: "https://test.com/"


Where can it appear?

Show a sample row with uptime

The repeated .* are a serious antipattern. Specify what exactly you want to match, otherwise the engine can spend a lot of time on lines where the input is not exactly the expected form.

you can try this code to match client an request for example and if there was another phrase like "test" between them, it could be ignored.
client: (?[^,]+),( test: )?((?[^,]+),)? request: (?[^,]+)
as you noticed, "test:" and which comes after it is optional.

in this way, you can modify your code.
/^(?<timestamp>\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[(?<log_level>\w+)\] (?<pid>\d+)#(?<tid>\d+): \*(?<connection>\d+) (?<message>.+?)(?:, uptime: (?<uptime>\d+\.\d+))?, client: (?<client_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+), server: (?<server>\S+), request: "(?<request_method>\w+) (?<request>[^"]+) HTTP\/(?<http_version>\d\.\d)", host: "(?<host>[^"]+)", referrer: "(?<referrer>[^"]+)"

try this code. if there is uptime it will fill it and if there isn't, it won't .
